# Submit form using JS and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have little problem with JS and AJAX, i dont know this languages. I know php and i have applied for position php developer, now i have some tasks to do and i stucked at one. It is simple task, form, submit, process information, store in DB, and send. Only problem is i have to use AJAX to submit form, i done little research and somehow i made wrote this code but it doesnt work.

```
<div>
        <form method="POST" action="add.php" id="form">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="Email">
            <textarea name="content" id ="content">Message</textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"> 
        </form>
        <a href="send.php">Send messages from database</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // When click on button store values from form fields into variables
            $("form").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var content = $("#content").val();
                // Check if fields are empty 
                if (email=="" || content="") {
                    alert("Please fill all fields");
                }
                // AJAX code to submit form
                else {
                    $.ajax ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: ("#form").attr('action');
                        data: { "email": email, "content": content},
                        cache: false,
                        success: function() {
                            alert("Data successfully forwarded to add.php");
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

IN form can i use input type button instead of submit (so no need for preventDefault in JS) and in JS i do it 
$("#submit").click(function.....

I think i have tried all combinations and when form is submited it goes with default, no JS activated...

**SOLVED:** problem was in IF statment, content="" instead of content=="", OMG how i overlooked that...

Comment: `url: ("#form").attr('action');`  What is the name of this file?  url (default: The current page), Type: String, 
A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.

Comment: Look at your javascript console you should see that you have a syntax error, `url: ("#form").attr('action');` its supposed to be a `,` at the end

Comment: Beyond the comma issue.. where do you want the data sent?  Hint: I'm thinking add.php is a pretty good place...

Comment: Yes add.php is place, but i didnt wanted it to be hardcoded so i used ("#form").attr('action') to pull URL from form, if you understand me..

Comment: `$("#form").submit(...`   ?  Also is jQuery loading correctly?

Comment: that is main problem here, i cant force it to go through JS every time i test it and submit form it goes with default no JS activating...

Comment: Can you remove the solution out of your question and submit it as a proper answer? (Slightly related to Meta question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309266/2564301)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `serialize()` method (described bellow) instead of manually getting the value of each field of your form in order to build the JSON object.

```
 $('#form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({ 
            data: $(this).serialize(), 
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            success: function() {
                alert("Data successfully forwarded to add.php");
            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
```

Comment: The `serialize()` method isn't to be found.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions, yes you are right, you can use an `input` of type `button` and you don't necessary need to depend on submitting the form. Here is how you'd write it without form submission:

```
<div>
    <form method="POST" action="add.php" id="form">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="Email">
        <textarea name="content" id ="content">Message</textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="SendAjax();"> 
    </form>
    <a href="send.php">Send messages from database</a>
</div>
<script>
    // When click on button store values from form fields into variables
    function SendAjax() {
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var content = $("#content").val();
        // Check if fields are empty 
        if (email=="" || content=="") {
            alert("Please fill all fields");
        }
        // AJAX code to submit form
        else {
            $.ajax ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "type your URL here",
                data: { "email": email, "content": content},
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    alert("Data successfully forwarded to add.php");
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you can see, I prefer to specify the URL in AJAX instead of taking it from the form's action which I sometimes have it set to a different URL from the AJAX. However, if you want to take the URL from the form's action, then fix that line in your code to be:

```
url: $("#form").attr('action'),
```

Comment: nice explanation! In the ajax submit code, there should be a comma after the "type your URL here" instead of a semi-colon

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your `ajax` call.

```
$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: ("#form").attr('action'); // This is bad JSON
    data: { "email": email, "content": content},
    cache: false,
    success: function() {
        alert("Data successfully forwarded to add.php");
    }
});
```

Replace that line with:

```
url: $("#form").attr('action'),
```

Comment: well i fixed all error but main problem remains, cant trigger JS on form submit, it goes default...
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

Comment: @Constantine1001 any javascript errors in the console?